# How to generate a non-linear colormap/colorbar?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

I would like to show a non-uniform colorbar as in the first picture. I have tried the code below. 'mycamp4' is a colormap manually saved. The result is shown as the second figure. The number `0.1` and `1.5` will be too closed too see. How can I make the colorbar like in the first picture?

```
v = [0.1 1 1.5 5 7.5 10 30];
v_2 = [0.1 1.5 5 7.5 10 30];
contourf(X,Y,pdf_normal',v);
h = colorbar;
load('MyColormaps','mycmap4');
set(gcf,'Colormap',mycmap4);
set(h, 'YTick', v_2)
```

**Picture 1:**

[image]

**Picture 2:**

[image]

Comment: maybe this helps: [logarithmic colorbar](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152310)

Comment: You mean you want a non-uniform colormap? `colorbar` normally just displays what `colormap` is. I assume you've tried [`colormapeditor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html). You should search for custom colormap on the File Exchange.

Comment: Sidenote, The bar in the first picture seems to have values above 30, whilst your second colorbar only shows values untill 30.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I think they are not related. Just examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a step by step explanation.

First consider the following example:

```
[X,Y,Z1] = peaks;

figure(1)
[~,h1] = contourf(X,Y,Z1,20);
a1 = colorbar;
colormap(jet)
caxis([-6,6])
```

which will give you the following plot:

[image]

It has linear data and a linear colormap. Now I want to scale the `Z`-Data to get it non-linear like in your case. I chose a simple squaring of the data.

```
Z2 = get(h1,'ZData');
scalefactor = @(x) sign(x).*x.^2;
Z2 = scalefactor(Z2);
```

Thats the actual example data, similar to yours:

```
figure(2)
[~,h2] = contourf(X,Y,Z2,20);
a2 = colorbar;
colormap(jet)
caxis([-6^2,6^2])
```

[image]

Now we have non-linear data, but still a linear `colormap` and `colorbar`.

**Until now everything was to generate example data similar to yours.**

---

**Now the actual answer:**

Get the data of your plot:

```
Z3 = get(h2,'ZData');
```

and scale it with a relation you hopefully know more or less:

```
descalefactor = @(x) sign(x).*abs(x).^(1/2);
Z3 = descalefactor(Z3);
```

Plot that scaled data:

```
figure(3)
[~,h3] = contourf(X,Y,Z3,20);
a3 = colorbar;
colormap(jet)
caxis([-6,6])
```

get the `Y-Ticks` and `scale it with the inverse function`, like your data:

```
ticks = get(a3,'YTick');
ticks = scalefactor(ticks);
```

set these inversly scaled colorbar ticks:

```
set(a3,'YTickLabel',ticks)
```

and you finally get a seemingly linearized plot (but you could just backup your non-linear data from before), with a with non-linear colormap and colorbar ticks.

[image]

As expected, the plot looks the same like in the first the example, but with a scaled colorbar axis.

If you don't have any functional relationship, try to get one, e.g. with the curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: Hi @thewaywewalk, Many thanks!! It seems working. I will have a try!

Comment: Quick note: I've found that if you change the size of the window such that the number of tick marks on the colorbar changes, they will no longer correctly match the colorbar (in fact, they will repeat themselves if a new tick is added). You have to rescale the colorbar again after resizing the figure.

Comment: @MarkH this is true, this is why you should **create** the figure already in the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the colormap and the ticks in the colorbar, but the colorbar itself is based on linear intervals and you can't change that.

There's a workaround though.

lets say you want your colorbar like that in picture 1 with N nonlinear intervals (e.g. color_limits = [1 2 20], if N=2).
you have to:

1) define another variable for your data. e.g.

```
data2 = nan(size(data));
for i=1:N
   b = data>color_limits(i) & data>=color_limits(i+1);
   data2(b) = i-0.5;
end
```

Basically you are binning data, using the intervals in color_limits, into a different variable data2 that you will display

2) make your image of data2

3) define the colorbar limits: caxis([0 N])

4) define a colormap with N colors, e.g. colormap(jet(N))

5) customize the ticks in the colorbar

Answer (score 0):

When you try `doc colorbar` you will find a reference to the colormap. And after trying `doc colormap` they basically give 3 options to set the color map.

1. Enter a map (for example one obtained by `get` or one designed earlier, this is what you tried)
2. Select a built-in colormap with the Property Editor.
3. Use the Colormap Editor, accessible from Edit > Colormap on the figure menu.

@horchler already mentioned it, but I assume you have not heard about the [colormap editor](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html) before. Hence I would suspect that option 3 is most suitable for you.

Comment: Dear Dennis,

Many thanks for your reply. Actually I have tried colormap ediotor (“mycmap4” in my original code). But it does not change the scale of the colorab. For example, I want the distance between 0.1 to 1 to to be the same as that between 1 to 2.5. I think the log scale colorbar mentioned by @thewaywewalk is close to what I want. But what I need is not a log scale but a "customized" scale.

Comment: The only way I see then is to linearize your data completely, with the relation you intend. And then use custom tick labels.

Answer (score 0):

one can try Recolor_contourf. It has two more functions and easy to use. 
In its help the example given as follows. The function is submitted by me. let me know if face any issue

```
X=1:10;Y=1:10;
C=rand(10,10)*150;
c=colormap(jet(7));
L=[10 20 50 60 70 100];
[cdd hc]=contourf(X,Y,C,[-5 L]);
Recolor_contourf(hc,c,L,'vert');
```