# Matlab: How to use a suitable color bar?

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, contour, colorbar

I have a picture which shows the magnitude of some value in terms of color, like this one:

[image]

The higher the magnitude, the more it looks red. However there are only a few points at the edge has very high values and most of the points have much lower values. If a colorbar with equal intervals is used the picture just looks blue throughout and the values in most areas cannot be distinguished.

Is it possible to set a colorbar that has, say, exponentially increasing intervals (or others) so that the center part can also show different colors?

Comment: Did you try applying a non-linear transform to your data?  How about `log`?

Comment: @rayryeng I have considered that, but it seems that it would be easier for people to read if only the colorbar is adjusted instead of the data.

Comment: @KelvinS See the bottom answer here, might help: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152310

Comment: [This answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100066-how-do-i-create-a-logarithmic-scale-colormap-or-colorbar) from MATLAB Central could be useful: It applies a `log10`, rescales the result, and sets the ticks in the colorbar correctly. (Yes, I know, it does adjust the data, not only the colorbar..)

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613841/how-to-generate-a-non-linear-colormap-colorbar as the OP specifies that they don't want to scale their data, only the map. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dan I disagree. But it's probably a matter of taste. You lose a lot of information by using a colorbar with a non-linear color distribution. Maintaining a useful colorbar and still get a balanced representation of your data probably requires scaling the data. I'd go for the duplicate option -> matter of taste

Comment: @thewaywewalk Dan is right, readers are usually more comfortable with un-scaled data. The other post (and many others) only offers solutions which requires scaling the data.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I agree that yours looks better and is likely more readable. Rather have log incrementing ticklabels that are physically linearly spaced n the screen. I just think it's not a duplicate because the OP asked for something else (albeit in the comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, it's not quite right but it's close. The idea is to make your own log spaced colour map. I do it by using linear interpolation between log spaced break points. It could probably be improved to use [logarithmic interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238103) (and maybe have better end cases):

First I simulate some data (open to suggestions for simulating data that better illustrates this example):

```
M = exp(rand(50)*10)
```

Then plot it (ignore the `figure(2)`, that's just to make this match the image later)

```
n = 64

figure(2)
imagesc(M)
colormap(jet(n))
colorbar
```

now create a log spaced colour map

```
linMap = jet(n);
breaks = round(0:n/5:n)';
breaks(1) = 1;
cBreaks = linMap(breaks,:);
idx = 2.^(6:-1:1)';
idx(end) = 0; %// this part is hacky
logMap = interp1(((idx)/64)*max(M(:)),flipud(cBreaks),linspace(0,max(M(:)),64)); %// based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically

figure(1)
imagesc(M)
colormap(logMap)
colorbar
```

results in

[image]

as you can see, the data remain unchanged and the data inspector still gives you back the same values but the colour bar is pretty much on a log scale now. I'd be interested to see what this looks like on your data.

Comment: I am trying your code with R2014a, there is an error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in Untitled2 (line 13)
cBreaks = linMap(breaks,:);" How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: @KelvinS what are your values for `n` and `breaks`? You should probably change that `5` to be the value to makes `2^(x+1) = n`. So when `n` is `64` then `x` is `5` as `2^(5+1)` is `64

Comment: I am using n=64 and breaks = round(0:n/5:n)'; (exactly your code). I have just found that if the first entry in breaks is 0 it cannot be put in the function linMap. Does it depends on version of Matlab?

Comment: @KelvinS oops, left off a line. You're right, it can't have that `0` in it. I just changed it to `1`. It's what I meant by not having great edge conditions.

Comment: @Kelvin can you link to an image of what the end result was on your data?

Comment: It becomes like this, https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk6d2n63twtuqdr/bar2.jpg?dl=0    Not completely satisfactory but at least I know the way to set exponential scale bar so that I can fine tune it.

Comment: Hmmm so that didn't do much at all. I would increase `n` and then change the number of breakpoints and see if that helps at all