# MATLAB: Equivalent distance between colour-map tick labels

Tags: matlab, plot, colormap

Considering the following code for plotting this figure, `code1` plots this figure using colour map defined from `get_my_color_map` function. Everything is fine so far except for the distribution of tick on the colour bar. I do not want it to be shown in a linear way. I want the colour ticks to be distributed with the equivalent space between members of this matrix:

```
[-40 -30 -20 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613841/h) however, I have no idea about how to fix the problem in my own case.

[image]

```
function code1()

[x,y] = meshgrid([-8:.2:8]);
Z = (4+x-0.5*x.*x).*1./(2+sin(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(4*pi)));
C=Z;
surf(x,y,Z,C)
ticks = [-40 -30 -20 -10 -9:5];
mycolormap=get_my_color_map(min(ticks),max(ticks));
colormap(mycolormap);
hC=colorbar;
ticks_string=strread(num2str(ticks),'%s');
set(hC,'YTick',ticks);
set(hC,'YTick',ticks);
set(hC,'ylim',[min(ticks) max(ticks)]);

end

function [ mycolormap ] = get_my_color_map(blue_min,red_max)

    mycolormap=[];

    for k= blue_min:-1 % add blue
        if k>=-10
            blue=-k/10.0*0.7;
        else
            blue=0.7+(-k-10.0)/(-10-blue_min)*0.3;
        end
        mycolormap=[mycolormap; 1-blue, 1-blue, 1]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
    mycolormap=[mycolormap; 1, 1, 1]; % add white
    for k= +1:red_max % add red
        red=k/red_max;
        mycolormap=[mycolormap; 1, 1-red, 1-red]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end

end
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to change this line of your code? `ticks = [-40 -30 -20 -10 -9:5];`

Comment: @A_C How should I change it?

Comment: just put the tick you want to appear on your colorbar. `ticks=[-40 -30 -20 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5]`

Comment: @A_C, are you joking me? have you tried `ticks = [-40 -30 -20 -10 -9:5]` and see the results?

Comment: @duche ok. now i see the problem. not just the ticks. too bad that i'll not tell you how